# URL routes - registering problem

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I've been using ASP.NET MVC for a few weeks, looking screencast, reading tutorials and so on. It turns out to be very interesting technology for me and I started to experimenting with it. I wrote simple web application which simply gets data from one table and shows it.

All works fine on my dev environment, but when I tried to "deploy" my simple web app onto my hosting I encountered a problem - URL routing was not working. After some digging into the problem I discovered, that for some reason Routes table is empty.

What may cause the problem? Why Application_Start method would not be called? And how to solve this problem?

P.S. I created my test web app using ASP.NET MVC 1.0 // template ASP.NET MVC Project.
IIS7 runs in Intergrated mode, and I do not have access to its administration (only via web.config files).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be deployment problem - I was not copying Global.asax file among the others.